# Are Internet Explorers "Tracking Protection" able to prevent AddThis canvas fingerprinting?

Tags: privacy, user-tracking, fingerprinting, internet-explorer

A paper on web tracking mechanisms identifies the web-tracking company AddThis as a major user of canvas fingerprinting.

Are IE:s Tracking Protection, provided Tracking Protection Lists including AddThis entries, able to prevent user identification by AddThis using canvas fingerprinting?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not trying to be mean or unhelpful but I don't know why people keep asking questions about whether Microsoft products and software are able to protect them from security threats. Just give up. Look into this https://adblockplus.org/blog/adblock-plus-and-the-canvas-fingerprinting-threat and read how its possible to prevent canvas fingerprinting. Then compare that to how tracking prevention works on IE.

Comment: Thank you for the link. As EasyList provides the EasyPrivacy subscription also in the form of a Tracking Protection list I assume that canvas fingerprinting will be prevented.

Comment: Perhaps they ask because they're not concerned about their own browsing, but are interested in how many users are affected by this sort of tracking?  Perhaps they ask because they are using a browser that does not support Adblock Plus?

Comment: Understandable, sorry for writing you off so quickly qnyz

Answer (score 0):

Yes.
AddThis uses JavaScript’s to perform canvas fingerprinting. If the URL (or a part of it) of the script is marked for blocking in a loaded Tracking Protection List, IE will not load the script.

EasyList provides a Tracking Protection List subscription, called EasyPrivacy, which includes AddThis URLs for blocking.

https://easylist.adblockplus.org/en/#easyprivacy